# CodeIgniter multiple file upload returns false

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I want to upload files after the successful insertion of some data into the database but the `file uploading` does not work.

The following is my code for file upload but it's not uploading.

**Controller**

```
public function saveReceipt(){
    $doc=$this->receipt_m->saveReceipt_m();
    if($doc){
      $countfiles = count($_FILES['attatchments']['name']);

      for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){

        if(!empty($_FILES['attatchments']['name'][$i])){

          // Define new $_FILES array - $_FILES['file']
          $_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['attatchments']['name'][$i];
          $_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['attatchments']['type'][$i];
          $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['attatchments']['tmp_name'][$i];
          $_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['attatchments']['error'][$i];
          $_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['attatchments']['size'][$i];

          // Set preference
          $config['upload_path'] = base_url("assets/attachments"); 
          $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|txt';
          $config['max_size'] = '5000'; // max_size in kb
          $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['attatchments']['name'][$i];

          //Load upload library
          $this->load->library('upload',$config); 
          $arr = array('msg' => 'something went wrong', 'success' => false);
          // File upload
          if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){

           $data = $this->upload->data(); 
           $arr = array('msg' => 'Image has been uploaded successfully', 'success' => true);

          }
        }

      }
      echo json_encode($arr);
    }else{
      $response=array("status"=>false);
    }
   }
```

**View**

```
<form class="horizontal-form" name="frmSaveReceipt" id="frmSaveReceipt"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
     <input type="file" name="attatchments[]" id="file" multiple="multiple">
   </form
```

Comment: so you get returned `"status" false `? that means $doc doesn't return anything, which means you need to analyze in your model `receipt_m` the function `saveReceipt_m()`, please add the relevant code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use move_uploaded_file() to upload multiple file....

```
$filename = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['attatchments']['name']);$i++){

if(!empty($_FILES['attatchments']['name'][$i])){
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attatchments']['tmp_name'][$i],
'assets/attachments'.$_FILES['attatchments']['name'][$i]);
 $filename[$i] = $_FILES['attatchments']['name'][$i];
 }
}
```

Now use loop on $filename to upload multiple file in your database..

Answer (score 0):

below code working for me please try this
 Controller code is below

```
$info=$this->input->post();
$data = array();
  // If file upload form submitted

$countfiles = count($_FILES['galleryImage']['name']);

 for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){

if(!empty($_FILES['galleryImage']['name'][$i])){

      // Define new $_FILES array - $_FILES['file']
  $_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['galleryImage']['name'][$i];
  $_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['galleryImage']['type'][$i];
  $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['galleryImage']['tmp_name'][$i];
  $_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['galleryImage']['error'][$i];
  $_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['galleryImage']['size'][$i];

      // Set preference
  $config['upload_path'] = './images/'; 
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
      $config['max_size'] = '5000'; // max_size in kb
      $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['galleryImage']['name'][$i];

      //Load upload library
      $this->load->library('upload',$config); 

      // File upload
      if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
        // Get data about the file
        $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
        $filename = $uploadData['file_name'];

        // Initialize array
        //$data['filenames'][] = $filename;

        $color=array(
         "pageId"=>$info["pageId"],
         "meta_key"=>"gImage",
         "meta_value"=>$filename,
         "status"=>1
       );
        $insert=$this->pm->insert_data($table,$color);
      }
    }

  }
```

and views code is

```
 <?php
$url=site_url('pages/SavePageAttribute');
$options = array('class' => 'form-inline', 'id' => 'category', 'method' => 'post','style'=>'margin:10px');
echo form_open_multipart($url, $options);
?>
  <tr>
     <td> 
      <?php
         echo form_label('Gallery Image', 'galleryImage'); ?></td>
        <td> 
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="galleryImage[]" id="galleryImage" multiple="true">
         </td>
       </tr>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```